# Braintree payment method not showing

Tags: php, magento, braintree

I set up the Braintree payment method on Magento following [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-braintree-payment-method-magento-2.html) article.

My braintree account is a production account, not sandbox.

I use Magento 2.0.10 Community edition and the only thing i see in the console on chrome is telling me that the `website is taking credit card or a password in a non-secure context` (witch i wanted to ask, how do i make it secure trough Magento ?), and `jQuery.browser is deprecated`.

And i really do not understand why it **doesen't** show up as a payment method.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [review these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question with more details e.g. what steps did you follow to set up Braintree payment method, are you using Magento's [community](http://docs.magento.com/m2/2.0/ce/user_guide/payment/braintree.html?Highlight=braintree) or [enterprise](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/payment/braintree.html) edition, do you see any  specific errors, etc. This will help the SO community help you!

Comment: @Shea I edited the post, can you help me ?

Comment: I recommend that you [reach out to Magento support](https://magento.com/support). You may also want to [post your question on their Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/). Finally, you may wish to [explore their forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=braintree).